# Firefox 19 and RequestAnimationFrame not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, animation, setinterval, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to make this demo work on Firefox 19 but looks like RequestAnimationFrame is not beeing called properly.

http://awardwinningfjords.com/projects/sequence/apple.html

All other browsers and versions works fine, just on FF19 (Mac)

Anyone have this issue before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vendors have their specific prefix to this function. Some works with or without it.

So for firefox you have to use `mozRequestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: YEs. I'm using mozRequestAnimationFrame.

Answer (score 0):

It's being called fine, but the calls happen before the new image has a chance to load, so each time you're canceling the in-progress image load and starting a new one which likewise doesn't get a chance to complete.

You may want to pre-cache the images.

Comment: Yes. I preloaded all images but still not happening the animation.